# How can I make robocopy silent in the command line except for progress?

Tags: backup, robocopy

I'm using robocopy to do backups with a PowerShell script, and it's pretty awesome, except that I'd like it to only show the progress percentage while it copies and not all of the other information.

The other information clutters the command window, which I'd clean and simple so that it's easy to see the overall progress of the backup.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 265, accepted):

I added the following 2 parameters:
`/np /nfl`

So together with the 5 parameters from `AndyGeek's` answer, which are `/njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns` you get the following and it's silent:

`ROBOCOPY [source] [target]  /NFL /NDL /NJH /NJS /nc /ns /np`

```
/NFL : No File List - don't log file names.
/NDL : No Directory List - don't log directory names.
/NJH : No Job Header.
/NJS : No Job Summary.
/NP  : No Progress - don't display percentage copied.
/NS  : No Size - don't log file sizes.
/NC  : No Class - don't log file classes.
```

Comment: That's good. Note that in the original question I did specify that I still wanted the progress percentage, but this works well if you don't want anything to display.

Comment: There's still a "100%" message displayed.

Comment: @ScottChu you realise that to display 100% at the end, is not a progress bar, right? and would serve no use either. And anyhow, it does not display 100%. The answer posted makes robocopy completely silent

Comment: This still prints a single empty line which is noticeable in batch files.

Comment: `/nc /ns` is not necessary when `/nfl /ndl` is specified.

Comment: @wqw, just add a > NUL at the EOL, and the empty line is history.

Comment: @ScottChu This prints 100% when you use the /mt switch. I guess you will have to decide if you want multithreaded, or no %s shown

Comment: I still get file sizes in the log and use `robocopy /l /mir "$super_ordner" null /l /MT:64 /r:0 /w:0 /ns /np /nc /njh /njs /bytes /unilog:$log /lev:$Level`

Comment: /MT is bugged.  It breaks some other silent settings.  The only way around this is >nul.

Answer (score 47):

I did it by using the following options:

```
/njh /njs /ndl /nc /ns
```

Note that the file name still displays, but that's fine for me.

For more information on `robocopy`, go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy

Comment: /nfl to suppress file name

Comment: Appears if you use `/mir` or `/purge` the extra files are still logged. Can't find a way to turn that off.

Comment: note that with robocopy the progress bar is only %  per file, doesn't show progress with the overall number of bytes copied out of the total / % of that.

Comment: Very interesting @bbodenmiller appreciation... Very annoying logging these files...

Answer (score 34):

If you want no output at all this is the most simple way:

`robocopy src dest > nul`

If you still need some information and only want to strip parts of the output, use the parameters from `R.Koene's` answer.

Comment: I test `> log:nul` under win8.1 x64, there is a empty log file. `> nul` works as expected.

Comment: The "empty" `log` file this generates isn't even truly empty. It's just saving the data to an [alternate stream](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2013/03/24/alternate-data-streams-in-ntfs/) that is invisible to Explorer, but very much still present on the disk. (You can check by using the `dir /r` command to show it.) @IvanYan is correct, `> nul` is the correct command to discard the output entirely.

Answer (score 22):

In PowerShell, I like to use:

```
robocopy src dest | Out-Null
```

It avoids having to remember all the command line switches.

Comment: When doing this, it immediately killed the command with no warning. I was using `/PURGE`.

Comment: Out-Null should have no effect on the execution of the robocopy command. It simply redirects the output stream. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/4.0/microsoft.powershell.core/out-null You might try removing the Out-Null to see if the discarded output offers any clue to what's happening.

Answer (score 4):

robocopy also tends to print empty lines even if it does not do anything. I'm filtering empty lines away using command like this:

```
robocopy /NDL /NJH /NJS /NP /NS /NC %fromDir% %toDir% %filenames% | findstr /r /v "^$"
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, if you want it to be absolutely silent, is to redirect the output to a file (and optionally delete it later).

```
Robocopy src dest > output.log
del output.log
```

Comment: also > NUL just chucks the output away, no file to worry about.

Comment: or pipe to `Out-Null` in PowerShell

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it is correct but I used this in Gitlab and it works:

```
robocopy <src> <dst> *.dll *.exe *.bat /E; $LastExitCode
```

Answer (score -1):

The > null does not work in the quotes. It sees the > null as the batch filename.

The robocopy no output worked!!!

Here is the new batch file:

```
robocopy /mir /B /r:1 /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns /np c:\EnvBackup c:\offsite_backup\EnvBackup

robocopy /mir /B /r:1 /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns /np c:\shares c:\offsite_backup\shares

robocopy /mir /B /r:1 /nfl /ndl /njh /njs /nc /ns /np c:\Quickbooks_Backup c:\offsite_backup\Quickbooks_Backup
```

Comment: `null` doesn't work because it should be `nul`.

Answer (score -4):

There's no need to redirect to a file and delete it later.
Try:

```
Robocopy src dest > null
```

Comment: This creates a file `null` and writes the log to it. It quiets it in the command line at the cost of storage drive writes.

Comment: I think OP meant to type `nul` (not `null`), which is a special reserved file name on Windows that is similar to `/dev/null` on Linux. Still, this doesn't answer OP's question.