# Having XCopy copy a file and not overwrite the previous one if it exists (without prompting)

Tags: xcopy

I'm sending commands to a remote computer in order to have it copy a file.
I want the file to be copied, but not to overwrite the previous file with the same name (if it exists).
I also need the command to run without any prompts (xcopy likes to prompt whether the target name I've specified is file or directory, and it will also prompt about overwriting a file).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to make it NOT overwrite as far as I know. but /Y will make it overwrite. and /I will get rid of the file/dict prompt. See `xcopy /?` for all options

Comment: Thanks.. Eventually I had to make it in two stages - first check for existence and then act accordingly.

Answer (score 76):

I have good results with `xcopy /d`.

It will copy NEWER files, and since we can assume that existing files have same time-stamp, you will copy only files that don't exist.

Comment: I use xcopy source dest /d /y /s

Comment: new thing I discovered recently, regarding xcopy /s /d /y ...  while copying directory structure, it will CREATE and then DELETE destination folders if no files match the mask that is given.  very strange, and sometimes very odd.

Comment: I found the /D option actually copies IFF the file already exists in the destination folder and is OLDER than the same named file from source. So the file HAS to exist first. Is there a way to XCOPY if there is no file in the destination?

Answer (score 34):

just in case anyone else finds this: 
robocopy x:\sourcefolder Y:\destfolder /s /e /r:0 /z

much better than xcopy, even gives you a table at the end informing of any failed or skipped files. Doesn't prompt to not overwrite.

Comment: you sir are a gentleman and a scholar, at first didn't think it "wasn't overwriting" but then I started getting "100% New File ....."

Comment: For anyone else since the question was for one file, based on this answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935583/how-to-skip-existing-and-or-same-size-files-when-using-robocopy, the command could be  robocopy x:\sourcefolder Y:\destfolder /XO. And to make the command (like XCopy) silent you can include the commands provided here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898127/how-can-i-make-robocopy-silent-in-the-command-line-except-for-progress

Answer (score 7):

Well, there's a certain remedy! It has helped me with saving much of my effort and time on Win10 while writing a setup for our product demo.

Just try to use piping:

**@ECHO N|COPY** **/-Y** *SourceFiles*  *Destination*

As an example I used this piece of code so that I would have a clean gentle quiet and safe copy!

```
@FOR /D %%F in ("FooPath") DO @(
   @ECHO N|COPY /-Y ^"%%~npdxF\*.*^" ^"GooPath^" 3>NUL 2>NUL >NUL
)
```

where obviously **FooPath** is the source and **GooPath** is the destination.

Enjoy!

(main source: https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html)

Comment: This should have been the official answer

Answer (score 5):

Following command copy files and folder but not override file if already exist.

```
xcopy "*.*" "C:\test\"  /s /y /d
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the replace command.  It has two modes:  to add files that don't exist there or replace files that do exist.  You want the previous mode:

```
replace <path1> <path2> /A
```

Comment: An OK option, however you cannot use this with /S to include sub-directories.

Comment: I really like this option, but be warned that it fails with "Path not found" if the destination folder does not exist, and there does not appear to be an option to force creation of the destination folder if it is not present.

Answer (score 2):

I had to copy AND rename files, so I got the prompt about creating a file or a directory.

This is the, rather "hackish" way I did it:

```
ECHO F | XCOPY /D "C:\install\dummy\dummy.pdf" "C:\Archive\fffc810e-f01a-47e8-a000-5903fc56f0ec.pdf"
```

XCOPY will use the "F" to indicate it should create the target as a file:

```
C:\install>ECHO F   | XCOPY /D "C:\install\dummy\dummy.html" "C:\Archive\aa77cd6e-1d19-4eb4-b2a8-3f8fe60daf00.html"
Does C:\Archive\aa77cd6e-1d19-4eb4-b2a8-3f8fe60daf00.html specify a file name or directory name on the target
(F = file, D = directory)? F
C:\install\dummy\dummy.html
1 File(s) copied
```

I've also verified this command leaves existing files alone. (You should too :-)