# Batch Delete Directory Error

Tags: batch-file, copy, dos

I am working on some code for a friend. This is what I have so far. It is supposed to be a backup script.

```
@echo off
title Backup Script
color 5a
if exist E:\backup goto prev
mkdir E:\backup
goto prev
:prev
echo Press any key to start Backup...
pause>nul
rd E:\backup /s /q
mkdir E:\backup\Desktop
mkdir E:\backup\Documents
msg * "Do not Close out previous Windows until Done."
copy "C:\Documents and Settings\Person\Desktop" "E:\backup\Desktop"
copy "C:\Documents and Settings\Person\My Documents" "E:\backup\Documents"
echo "Finished! Press any key to Exit."
pause>nul
exit
```

But whenever I make a change in the originating directory, it does not show on the backup drive.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean ? It don't do the copy ? You'll better use `robocopy` to just copy the new files or delete the files who don't exists anymore (`/purge` switch)

Answer (score 0):

The `copy` command is for copying files, not directories. If you want to copy a directory tree, consider using `xcopy`, or as SachaDee suggests, `robocopy`. As a bonus, `robocopy /XO` can skip files that have already been backed up [that haven't changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935583/). Then you wouldn't have to `rd /q /s e:\backup` before every backup, and subsequent backups will go much more quickly. [Full details on robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html).