# How to configure PhpStorm File Watcher to copy file

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to set up file watcher in PhpStorm on one file, that will copy that file to different location in project after file change/save?

Comment: What exactly the purposes of this? Because there could be 2 solutions: 1) using Deployment -- it can do auto deployment of all modified files (unless excluded); target can be another folder/network disk .. or proper remote host; 2) File Watcher -- works on actual modified files; you just need to create a batch/shell script that will copy those files for you (e.g. standard `copy` command on Windows) and use that script in `program` filed of File Watcher (and pass file name as a parameter)

Comment: Number 2 - thanks for tip, I'll create bash script as program and try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a batch/shell script for this as has been suggested in comments. You can just use *xcopy.exe* as a program. On Windows 10 it resides in `C:\Windows\System32` folder.

One way to set it up would be:

**Arguments:** `src\$FileName$ dist /iy`

**Working directory:** `$ProjectFileDir$`

In this case you are copying top-level files from `src` directory to `dist` directory of your project. `/i` tells xcopy that the destination is a folder and `/y` supresses the prompt to confirm overwriting.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in this [other Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27817352/334963) is better to use `robocopy`.

I created a **Watcher** with **WebStorm** > *Settings* > *Tools* > *File Watchers*:

- File type: `any`
- Scope: `Changed Files`
- Program: `C:\Windows\System32\robocopy.exe`
- Arguments: `$FileDir$ C:\MyDestinationDir\$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$ $FileName$`
- Working Directory: `$ProjectFileDir$\src`