# Test IF file exist, ELSE xcopy these two files

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, testing, xcopy

Morning all.

So I've been up hours trying to cobble together -a variety of replies to other posts- into my own code in order to see if I could get something usable. No-go. I'm sufficiently lost in the sauce that I've now got to ask for some help from you.

Background:
OS: Windows 10
I use the program text2folders.exe to create 20-30 new folders on a secondary drive every night.
Primarily, I have a base file "aGallery-dl.bat" that I populate each folder with using an xcopy batch file. Secondarily, from time to time I update the source file "aGallery-dl.bat" using the same xcopy and this overwrites the older target file, populating *all folders* with the newest "aGallery-dl.bat" (whether they need it or not). All is well.

```
@echo off
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy /y /d ".\aGallery-dl.bat" "%%a\"
```

I've recently decided I want to add two new files to each folder and have expanded my xcopy to include these. All is well.

```
@echo off
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy /y /d ".\aGallery-dl.bat" "%%a\"
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder.jpg" "%%a\"
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder2.jpg" "%%a\"
```

Folder.jpg
[a big red X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3CsM.jpg)

Folder2.jpg
[a big yellow ! mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq0gm.jpg)

When I choose to run a "aGallery-dl.bat" in a given folder (again, one of 100's), it first deletes Folder.jpg then renames Folder2.jpg to Folder.jpg. This has the effect of the red X being replaced by the yellow ! when viewing the folder in File Explorer parent folder. Secondly, it calls "gallery-dl.exe." I use going from red to yellow to let me know I've run "aGallery-dl.bat" at least once. All is well.

```
rem @echo off
del .\Folder.jpg
ren .\Folder2.jpg Folder.jpg
FOR /F %%i IN ('cd') DO set FOLDER=%%~nxi
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gallery-dl\gallery-dl.exe" -d "U:\11Web\gallery-dl" --download-archive ".\aGDB.sqlite3" "https://www.deviantart.com/"%FOLDER%"/gallery/all"
del .\Folder.jpg
```

If "aGallery-dl.bat" completes successfully, it finally deletes the Folder.jpg (currently yellow !), and now the representative contents of the folder (usually DeviantArt .jpg's) are visible.

**Problem:**
When I have to re-run my original xcopy command to update "aGallery-dl.bat" in ALL FOLDERS, the Folder.jpg and Folder2.jpg will be re-copied to all folders, defeating the purpose of deleting them once via "aGallery-dl.bat." I don't want to have to go back and re-run "aGallery-dl.bat" intermittently across 100's of folders (again, only those that have had aGallery-dl.bat run at least once). I need some type of test, that if "aGallery-dl.bat" is already present in the target folder, DO NOT xcopy Folder.jpg and Folder2.jpg aka vague example, below.

```
*********************************Some sort of test statement here!!!***********************

:aGallery-dlPresent
GOTO eof

:aGallery-dlNotPresent
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder.jpg" "%%a\"
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder2.jpg" "%%a\"
GOTO eof

:eof
```

**I had found a hopeful candidate test statement in the below (copied in its original form from what/where I read in other post), but am looking for ideas/replacements as I HAVE NO IDEA how to modify/inject/implement the below to work in the above.**

```
If exist \\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav xcopy \\%DIR%\%Folder%\123456789.wav D:\%New Folder%\ /y
```

[Having XCopy copy a file and not overwrite the previous one if it exists (without prompting)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152835/having-xcopy-copy-a-file-and-not-overwrite-the-previous-one-if-it-exists-withou)

Note: The below is a vague approximation of what it should all look like (barring having a correct -test statement-).

```
rem @echo off
*********************************Some sort of test statement here!!!***********************

:aGallery-dlPresent
GOTO eof

:aGallery-dlNotPresent
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder.jpg" "%%a\"
for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy ".\Folder2.jpg" "%%a\"
GOTO eof

:eof

for /D %%a in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*.*") do xcopy /y /d ".\aGallery-dl.bat" "%%a\"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command for copying a file is **COPY**. It is an internal command of Windows command processor `cmd.exe`. **XCOPY** is an eXtended file and directory copying **executable** in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32` which is deprecated since Windows Vista as there is even more powerful **ROBOCOPY** which is with full qualified file name `%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe`.

There is no need to use **XCOPY** or **ROBOCOPY** for this simple file copying task. **COPY** is enough on source files `aGallery-dl.bat`, `Folder.jpg` and `Folder2.jpg` don't have hidden attribute set and the same files in the target directories don't have read-only attribute set.

`.\` references the current directory which can be any directory. Windows Explorer sets the directory of the batch file as current directory on double clicking on a batch file. But this is nearly the only method to run a batch file on which the directory of the executed batch file is set automatically as current directory (except the batch file is stored on a network resource accessed using UNC path).

There is `%~dp0` to reference the path of the batch file. This path always ends with a backslash which means that no additional backslash is needed on concatenating the batch file path with a file or folder name. The usage of `%~dp0` makes it possible to reference files in same directory as the executed batch file independent on which directory is the current directory on execution of the batch file.

The batch file needed for your task is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /D %%I in ("U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart\*") do (
    if not exist "%%I\aGallery-dl.bat" (
        copy "%~dp0Folder.jpg" "%%I\"
        copy "%~dp0Folder2.jpg" "%%I\"
    )
    copy /Y "%~dp0aGallery-dl.bat" "%%I\"
)
endlocal
```

A file/folder name must be enclosed in `"` if containing a space or one of these characters `` &()[]{}^=;!'+,`~ ``. For that reason all file/folder names are enclosed in this batch file in double quotes although inside the batch files no file/folder name contains a space or one of the characters in the list. It is important to understand on batch file writing how a command line looks like after Windows command processor processed the command line. See following topics:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [How to debug a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42448601/3074564)

Windows interprets `*.*` like just `*` which means any file or folder name. For that reason it is enough to just write `*` and omit `.*`.

Please note that `for /D` ignores directories with hidden attribute set.

The batch file checks first for each subfolder if it does not contain the batch file `aGallery-dl.bat`. In this case it copies the two files `Folder.jpg` and `Folder2.jpg` from directory of executed batch file to current subdirectory of `U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart`.

Then the batch file `aGallery-dl.bat` is copied from directory of executed batch file to to current subdirectory of `U:\11Web\gallery-dl\deviantart` independent on its existence in the destination directory.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `call /?` ... explains `%~dp0` ... drive and path of argument 0 ... full batch file path.
- `cmd /?` ... outputs the help of Windows command processor executing a batch file.
- `copy /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also the chapters **Issue 6** and **Issue 7** in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60686543/3074564) why using `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion` and `endlocal` although not necessary by default and why using `I` instead of `a` as loop variable although `a` would work here, too.